# vmbuilder fails on chroot

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I am trying to install virtual machine with this command, but have no success:

```
vmbuilder kvm ubuntu --verbose --suite precise --flavour virtual \
--part partitions.txt --ip 192.168.1.3 --hostname edb1 --arch amd64 \
-o --libvirt qemu:///system --user someuser --pass somepass \
--raw /home/virtual-machines/edb1.disk1.img \
--raw /home/virtual-machines/edb1.disk2.img \
--domain somedomain.com --mem 4096 --cpus 4
```

This is the error:

```
...
I: Extracting xz-utils...
I: Extracting zlib1g...
W: Failure trying to run: chroot /tmp/tmp_JdKzu mount -t proc proc /proc
, stderr:
```

The host kernel is not original but modified by server provider. Why is the chroot needed for installation?

Answer (score 0):

That's how vmbuilder is designed, as a shortcut to installing the image using the VM, it builds it on disk using a chroot. chroot require root access unless the administrator has made allowances for you.

https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/jeos-and-vmbuilder.html

Try using sudo.

Comment: The problem was with kernel. After I changed the kernel, I was able to create the virtual machine.